# Nginx Ingress Controller not work(External Ip pending)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes

I have an non-EKS cluster with 3 EC2 instance.
I have a service NodePort with port 80:31080
I have install nginx ingress controller by helm.
I created an ingress.
But I don't know to use ingress with public IP of the node(EC2 instance).This is because I have a domain pointed to the Node public IP.

So my question is how to use Public IP of node to access to K8s cluster non-EKS ?

Show all:

[image]

My ingress file:

[image]

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get faster recommendations from the community

Comment: Can you describe your Ingress to show more information? If you want to use IP address of nodes, you can create service NodePort.